# From list of decimal to hours / minutes

Tags: python, datetime

I have a list like the following:

```
T = [10.749957462142994, 10.90579301143351, 10.981580990083001]
```

That contains `timestamp` in a decimal format

```
hours =  [ int(x) for x in T ]
minutes =[ (x*60) % 60 for x in T]

print("%d:%02d"%(hours[0], minutes[0]), "%d:%02d"%(hours[1], minutes[1]), "%d:%02d"%(hours[2], minutes[2]))
['10:44', '10:54', '10:58']
```

I would like to create a list of datetime without years-month-day but just hours and minutes.

I tried this:

```
from datetime import datetime
DT = []
for i,t in enumerate(T):
    string = str("%d:%02d"%(hours[i], minutes[i]))
    datetime_object = datetime. strptime(string, '%H:%M')
    DT.append(datetime_object)
```

However `DT` looks like the following:

```
DT
[datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 10, 44),
 datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 10, 54),
 datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 10, 58)]
```

How can I remove the information of year, day and month and have something like:

```
DT
[datetime.datetime( 10, 44),
 datetime.datetime( 10, 54),
 datetime.datetime( 10, 58)]
```

Comment: You don't want datetime.datetime, you want datetime.time.

Comment: I think your first code snippet already does a very good job, no? Depending on what you want to do further, why bother with the datetime/time overhead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple way to do it:

```py
import datetime

DUMMY_DATETIME = datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0)
HOUR = datetime.timedelta(hours=1)

T = [10.749957462142994, 10.90579301143351, 10.981580990083001]
DT = [(DUMMY_DATETIME + hours * HOUR).time() for hours in T]
```

A `timedelta` can be multiplied by a `float` (automatically rounding to microseconds), which lets you easily convert a fractional hours value into a `timedelta`, without having to manually do the multiplication/division/modulo by 60.

The date part (Y2K) of the `DUMMY_DATETIME` object is just there to make the `+` operator work (because `time + timedelta` is a `TypeError`, but `datetime + timedelta` is fine).  All that matters is the hours/minutes/seconds part being 0.

The expression `DUMMY_DATETIME + hours * HOUR` thus gives a timestamp that's the specified number of hours after the epoch.  And calling `.time()` on that object gives you the time, without the useless year/month/day part.

```py
>>> DT
[datetime.time(10, 44, 59, 846864), datetime.time(10, 54, 20, 854841), datetime.time(10, 58, 53, 691564)]
>>> [t.strftime('%H:%M') for t in DT]
['10:44', '10:54', '10:58']
```

Answer (score 1):

I've taken a slightly different approach:

```
from datetime import time, datetime, timedelta
T = [10.749957462142994, 10.90579301143351, 10.981580990083001]
values = [(datetime.min + timedelta(hours=t)).time() for t in T]
```

timedelta objects support arbitrary floats for the hours. The result is a rather simple 1 line of code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use datetime.time  or if you really want to use datetime.datetime then you can get the time only with datatime.datetime.time() method.